Prove that MLE can sometimes be biased
I am trying to find an example where the MLE (maximum likelihood estimator) can be biased.
My prof gave us a hint to look at the normal distribution:
$$ L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
I tried to do this in several parts.
Part 1: log-likelihood:
$$ L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
Taking the natural logarithm of both sides:
$$ \ln L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right) $$
Using the logarithm property $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$, we can separate the product:
$$ \ln L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right) $$
Using the logarithm property $\ln(a/b) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$ and $\ln(e^x) = x$:
$$ \ln L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) + \ln\left(\exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right)\right) $$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(\sigma^2) - \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
$$ = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(\sigma^2) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} $$
$$ = -\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2}\ln(\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 $$
Part 2: For the MLE of $μ$, we differentiate with respect to $μ$ and set to zero:
$$ \frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \mu} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu) = 0 $$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - n\mu = 0 $$
$$ \hat{\mu}_{MLE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \bar{X} $$
To prove unbiasedness of $\hat{\mu}_{MLE}$:
$$ E[\hat{\mu}_{MLE}] = E[\bar{X}] = E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \cdot n\mu = \mu $$
Part 3: For the MLE of $\sigma^2$, we differentiate with respect to $\sigma^2$ and set to zero:
$$ \frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \sigma^2} = -\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{2(\sigma^2)^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 = 0 $$
$$ \frac{n}{2\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{2(\sigma^2)^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 $$
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2 $$
Part 4: To prove bias of $\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE}$:
$$ E[\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE}] = E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2\right] $$
$$ = E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 - 2X_i\bar{X} + \bar{X}^2)\right] $$
$$ = E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2\bar{X}^2 + \bar{X}^2\right] $$
$$ = E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar{X}^2\right] $$
$$ = \frac{1}{n}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right] - E[\bar{X}^2] $$
$$ = E[X^2] - E[\bar{X}^2] $$
$$ = (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) - (\frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2) $$
$$ = \sigma^2 - \frac{\sigma^2}{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2 $$
Part 5: Actual value of $\sigma^2$:
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 $$
$$ E[\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE}] = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2 $$
To me it becomes obvious from here, we need a correction factor of $n/(n-1)$ for it to be unbiasedness:
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2_{unbiased} = \frac{n}{n-1}\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE} $$
$$ E[\hat{\sigma}^2_{unbiased}] = E[\frac{n}{n-1}\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE}] $$
$$ = \frac{n}{n-1}E[\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE}] $$
$$ = \frac{n}{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2 $$
$$ = \sigma^2 $$
Is this what my prof was likely suggesting?


Note:

$$ \ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) = \ln(1) - \ln(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}) $$
$$ = 0 - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) $$
$$ = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(\sigma^2) $$

Note:  $E[X^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$ for a normal distribution.
$$\sigma^2 = E[(X - \mu)^2]$$
$$\sigma^2 = E[X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2]$$
$$\sigma^2 = E[X^2] - 2\mu E[X] + \mu^2$$
$$\sigma^2 = E[X^2] - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2$$
$$\sigma^2 = E[X^2] - \mu^2$$
$$E[X^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$$

Note:  $E[\bar{X}^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$.
$$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$


In general: $Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2$. Thus:
$$E[\bar{X}^2] = Var(\bar{X}) + (E[\bar{X}])^2$$
$$E[\bar{X}] = \mu$$
$$Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$
Thus:
$$E[\bar{X}^2] = Var(\bar{X}) + (E[\bar{X}])^2$$
$$E[\bar{X}^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$$

Note: Basic formulas:

$$
Var(X) = \sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2]
$$
And
$$
\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2] 
= \mathbb{E}(X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2)
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - 2\mu \mathbb{E}(X) + \mathbb{E}(\mu^2)
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mu^2
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - [\mathbb{E}(X)]^2
$$

You don't "prove" it rather than give a counterexample.
A classical one is when $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are uniform $[0,\theta]$.
Then the likelihood function is
$$
L(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\theta^{-n} 1_{0\le x_1\le \theta}\cdot1_{0\le x_2\le \theta}\cdot...1_{0\le x_n\le \theta}=\theta^{-n}  1_{\min(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ge 0}
\cdot 1_{\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)\le \theta}
$$
which is maximised by setting $\hat \theta_{MLE}=\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ which is biased.

OP did give an example I think; he showed that the MLE for the variance of a normal distribution is biased, if I understood correctly.
